# Testing for equality across a sequential table

Tags: fennel

In [fennel](/questions/tagged/fennel), I can easily test that numerous values are equal, like so:

```
>> (=  1 1 1 1)
true
```

My question is, how do I do this for a sequential table (e.g., `[1 1 1 1]`)? My initial though was to use `table.unpack`, but when I run,

```
(= (table.unpack [1 1 1 1]))
```

I get the error,

> Compile error: unknown:1:0 Compile error: expected at least two arguments